# Download the multiple files with android download manager

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-download-manager

I want to download say 5 zip files from url so right now I am calling the DownloadManger 5 times.Is this approach ok or I should call the logic of downloading the files inside for loop by just calling the DownloadManger class once.
And also is this possible to download multiple files using Download manager and broadcast after last file completed the downloading.Please suggest some idea.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this approach ok

It is your only choice.

> or I should call the logic of downloading the files inside for loop by just calling the DownloadManger class once

A `DownloadManager.Request` object represents one file to be downloaded. [The `enqueue()` method on `DownloadManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#enqueue%28android.app.DownloadManager.Request%29) takes one `DownloadManager.Request` object. Hence, if you wish to download five files, you will need to call `enqueue()` five times. Whether you use a loop or something else is up to you.

> And also is this possible to download multiple files using Download manager and broadcast after last file completed the downloading

`DownlaodManager` will broadcast results after every download.

If you do not like how `DownloadManager` does the downloading, do the downloading yourself, using `HttpUrlConnection`, OkHttp, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In most samples it is used `extras.getLong(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1)` which returns the first successful download from a list. That's why we should use our own list of `downloadId`s to check status.